# How to make an image button in JSF

Tags: jsf, button, primefaces

I want to have a component that looks like a button, but instead of text it should contain an image. 
Because the standard button does not offer this functionality, I tried to use a `<h:commandLink>`:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{some_action}">
    <p:panel styleClass="some_style">
        <h:graphicImage value="#{some_image}">
    </p:panel>
</h:commandLink>
```

This doesn't work. The `<h:commandLink>` is translated into an `<a>` tag, and the `<p:panel>` into a `<div>`. `<a>`-tags may not contain `<div>`-tags, so the `<div>`-tag is automatically placed outside the `<a>`-tag. 
The result is that only the image is clickable, not the surrounding panel which is styled to look like a button. Is there a way to make the surrounding panel part of the link, or to put an image inside a button?

My project uses JSF and the Primefaces library:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can add an image to a [commandButton](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/commandButton.html):

Using the image attribute

```
<h:commandButton action="#{some_action}" image="button.gif" />
```

> Absolute or relative URL of the image
>   to be displayed for this button. If
>   specified, this "input" element will
>   be of type "image". Otherwise, it will
>   be of the type specified by the "type"
>   property with a label specified by the
>   "value" property.

Use CSS

```
<h:commandButton action="#{some_action}" styleClass="button" />

.button {
    background: white url('button.gif') no-repeat top;
}
```

Comment: The CSS is the best solution. The `<input type="image">` serves a different purpose.

Comment: I used a combination of your two options:
`<h:commandButton action="#{some_action}" image="#{some_image}" styleClass="#{some_class}" />`

I used the following css:
`.some_class {
 height: [heigt_of_image]px;
 width: [width_of_image]px;
 background: lightblue;
 border-style: outset;
 border-width: 2px;
 float: left;
 padding: 6px 8px;
 margin: 0px;
}`

The padding increases the button to the desired size.

Answer (score 8):

You could just move the div outside e.g.

```
<div class="myButton">
<h:commandLink action="#{some_action}" styleClass="clickAll">
        <h:graphicImage value="#{some_image}">
</h:commandLink>
</div>
```

And style the div that way.  Just make the anchor (a tag) display as a block and it should fill the whole div so it's all clickable.  For example in your CSS go:

```
.clickAll{
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried it, but unfortunately the `<p:panel>`-tag is translated into two nested divs: `<div class="myclass"><div class="some_primefaces_stuff"> <a href="some_location" class="clickAll"> [the image] </a></div></div>`. I can't control the css for the inner `<div>`, so its size constrains the size of the `<a>`.

Comment: If you must use the panel component, then if you're using JQuery you could use the nth child selector [http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/] to apply the relevant CSS style to the DIV which is a child of the div with .myclass

Answer (score 4):

If you can use an icon from PrimeFaces/JSF, then there is a simple and sound solution is

```
<p:column>
    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-wrench"
     style="border-width:0;background:none;"/>
</p:column>
```

It may help to avoid JavaScript code in JSF.

Comment: Thanks for this as I was looking for to reduce size of command button.

Answer (score 0):

If the image does not fit then add properties to a сss class:

```
.button {
    background: white url('button.gif') no-repeat top;
    width: 32px;   // button width
    height: 32px;  // button height
    background-size: contain;
    border: none;  // hide border of button
}
```